# Call Superclass method

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, how do I call an object's super class method?

For example, lets say I have an instance of an object "foo".

"foo" has a method that is overriden. I do not want to call this overriden method. Instead, I want to call the original method on the foo object instance.

You cannot do:

`[[instance super] super_method];` as far as I am aware. So how can I go about doing this?

I know I can add a method to foo:

```
-(void) callsuper
{
    [super super_method];
}
```

and do:

`[foo callsuper];`

Any other ways? I really don't want to create a method just to do that.

Comment: Why not just directly call `[super someMethod];` - Why create a function to call that ?

Comment: someMethod is override by foo's class; he want to by pass the subclass's implementation, and call the super class's one directly. Is it really possible? And I am curious what's the purpose / benefit doing so?

Comment: Is it any design pattern? we can call directly [fooInstance fooClassMethod];.

Comment: @Objective-J you can't.. For example I don't want to call `[super someMethod]`.. I want to call `[[fooInstance super] superMethod]` to by-pass the override instead of doing `[fooInstance callsuper]`. Again, this is because the method is overriden.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `super` does this for you. It is seen very commonly in `-init` methods. Here is an example.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

In this case, the `super` keyword is used to call this class' superclass implementation of the `-init` method. `super` can be used on any method that your superclass implements.